# Adding HTTP Basic Auth to Webpack Dev Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, basic-authentication

Is there a simple way to add simple HTTP Basic Authentication to the Webpack Dev Server in a Zero-Configuration-React-App.

What I did:

1. I've created a react app using `create-react-app`, then built my whole app.
2. I then ejected it using `npm run eject`.
3. Then I googled for hours and didn't find any hint.

Is there a configuration for this or do I have to add a middleware? Or is the only / easiest way to use webpack together with express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi yes you can please look at setup key in webpack config or this url
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-setup
i have been there facing such issues, you can simply use basic-auth package to overcome your need

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, you helped me solving it. I've summarized my solution here: https://medium.com/@msnajdr/adding-password-protection-to-zero-configuration-webpack-react-app-1bd3fc976996

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to do this is to use the [`express-basic-auth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth) middleware.

Install it as a dev dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev express-basic-auth
```

Then configure webpack as follows:

```
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    ...
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
      devServer.app.use(basicAuth({
        users: {
            'user1': 'password1',
            'user2': 'password2'
        },
        challenge: true
      }));

      return middlewares;
    }
  }
}
```

Or however you want it to work.